# What is wrong with the Django Forms BooleanField unit test case?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm totally stuck here.  Why does this test case fail?

```
class BogusForm(forms.Form):
    bogus_bool = forms.BooleanField() 

class TestBogusForm(TestCase):

    def test_bogus_false(self):
        query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
        query_dict.update({'bogus_bool': False})
        bogus_form = BogusForm(query_dict)
        self.assertTrue(bogus_form.is_valid())
```

It fails form field validation, **but only if bogus_bool is False when I update the QueryDict**.  If I say:

```
query_dict.update({'bogus_bool': True})
```

Then it passes validation.  What's going on here?  Is this a bug in Django Forms?

If I look at the QueryDict before I pass it to the BogusForm constructor, it looks like this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'bogus_bool': [False]}>
```

Which looks totally legit and correct to me.

Comment: There is a long discussion on this behavior in a relevant ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5957.

Answer (score 3):

From django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield)

> Since all Field subclasses have required=True by default, the
>   validation condition here is important. If you want to include a
>   boolean in your form that can be either True or False (e.g. a checked
>   or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in required=False
>   when creating the BooleanField.

Comment: Yeah, and when you do this, you can't tell the difference between "not present" and "set to False"

Comment: Well yeah, that's why they have the NullBooleanField for "not present". Admittedly the semantics of these 2 fields are not very clear at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is incorrect behavior.

This should do for a specific field:

```
class BogusForm(forms.Form):
    bogus_bool = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def clean_bogus_bool(self):
        field_name = 'bogus_bool'
        if field_name not in self.data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return self.cleaned_data[field_name]
```

This should do it for all bool fields on the form:

```
class BooleanFieldsRequiredMixin(forms.Form):
    def clean(self):
        for field_name, field in self.fields.iteritems():
            # Only BooleanField not subclasses of it.
            if type(field) is not forms.BooleanField:
                continue

            if field_name not in self.data:
                self._errors[field_name] = self.error_class(["This field is required."])

        return super(BooleanFieldsRequiredMixin, self).clean()


class BogusForm(BooleanFieldsRequiredMixin, forms.Form):
    bogus_bool = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

There is a way to make this nicer by not requiring that `required=False` bit on the boolean field, but it's not worth the effort at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your bogus_bool is a required field by default.

```
class BogusForm(forms.Form):
    bogus_bool = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: It's required and I've provided it, so what's the issue?  Why is the True value for bogus_bool behaving differently than the False value?  And, I want the form field to be required. :)

Comment: If it's required, then False is an invalid input. Boolean by definition is either True or False. Perhaps you want a NullBooleanField? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#nullbooleanfield

Comment: Why is False invalid input if it's a required boolean?  False is a valid boolean value, right?   I'll try out NullBooleanField, but Null is not an acceptable input for this form, so I'd rather not use it.

Comment: What you'll need then is a NullBooleanField with a clean_bogus_bool method to check you're getting either True or False and not None.

Surely it's obvious why False is not a valid input for a *required* BooleanField? HTML checkboxes don't send True or False, they send their value, or nothing at all.

Comment: No, it's not.  Forms are forms and Checkboxes are widgets.  This is totally mysterious behavior.  The fact that HTML checkboxes don't pass a value when unchecked should have nothing to do with the BooleanField, and should be part of the CheckboxWidget.

Comment: Ok, so by your logic any valid input should be enough to satisfy the `required` requirement. I.e. a required `CharField` should accept an empty string as valid input; a required `IntegerField` should accept 0; etc. Thankfully django takes the sane approach and requires truthy input for required fields.